# Какой компилятор и на каком языке программирования для работы можно полноценно использовать на Android

Tags: android

Суть вопроса такова. Я работаю на почте России оператором, там у меня куча времени на работе, и я хочу его потратить на изучение какого-либо языка программирования и использовать в работе на фрилансе (опыт кодинга на Java есть большой). Но под рукой только гаджеты на Android, никаких ноутбуков нет. Какой язык программирования или программа для андроида для этих целей подойдет больше всего.

Comment: Чего это вдруг Java урезанная? Весь андроид почти целиком на Java написан

Comment: @andreymal здорово правда? написан на Java, а с Java полноценно работать нет возможности (доступно, в общем то, только консольная  Java core да и то через одно место ...)

Comment: @pavlofff попробуйте прочитать хотя бы первые главы любого учебника по Android-разработке

Comment: Если вы называете Java и C++ для андроид "ограниченными и урезанными", то вы либо не попробовали их на самом деле, либо путаете язык и графические библиотеки. Да, на андроид вы вряд ли напишете приложение на JavaFX, но это не проблема Java, это проблема платформы JavaFX. Дополните вопрос конкретикой, чего вам не хватает такого, без чего миллионы разработчиков как-то живут. В противном случае словите кучу минусов и тревог за разжигание межпрограммерской агрессии, в т.ч. от меня =)

Comment: @andreymal как я понял, в вопросе речь идет о разработке десктопных/web java-программ на платформе андроид, а не разработке андроид-приложений на java. Приведите пример более менее годного стека из первых глав любого учебника, для разработки проекта с использованием swing, spring, hibernate, jpa да и любой десктоп/web технологии, отходящей от консольной core java

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий видимо речь идет о десктоп/web java-разработке на платформе андроид, а не разработке приложений для андроид, но Анатолию лучше бы уточнить, о чем именно он спрашивает. Кстати, именно JavaFX можно вполне сносно использовать для разработки андроид-приложений, в отличии от других дестопных java gui

Comment: «через сам телефон на Андроид писать десктопные приложения» — но зачем? Android вроде как в принципе не задумывался быть платформой для разработки.

Comment: Посмотрите на pydroid 3. Почти полноценный питон под андроидом, даже ткинтер есть. Причём отечественный продукт - из НГУ. Но писать код на мобильном устройстве то ещё удовольствие.